# dash: List declared functions

Tags: function, dash

What is the `dash` equivalent to `bash`'s:

```
compgen -A function
```

which lists the names of the declared functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no equivalent. `dash` has a very small number of [built-in commands](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/dash/dash.git/tree/src/builtins.def.in) and none of them list the declared functions.

Comment: Looking at the source code confirms this. The only places where the code iterates over all functions actually skip functions to look at hashed external command names only.