# ash: List functions

Tags: function, ash

Does `busybox ash` have an equivalent to `bash`'s:

```
compgen -A function
```

for listing the names of the declared functions?

(Not a duplicate of [dash: List declared functions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343297/dash-list-declared-functions): This is for `ash`, not `dash`).

Comment: Which of the many shells named ash are you referring to? I guess you want to know for all the shells out there, but maybe you've settled on a compatibility list?

Comment: You mean `busybox ash`?

Comment: @phk Yes. Edited.